# ggplot - plotting 2 different graphs next to each other

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

How would I go about putting 2 box plots next to each other?

For instance, say I want to compare "Average goals scored per game at home" with "Average goals conceded per game at home" across 3 football leagues, and for this purpose would like to use 2 box plots next to each other on the same graph (i.e. same axes) to give an accurate visual representation.

I have no problem plotting 1 box plot, but I don't know how to put the 2 plots on the same axes. I saw an explanation using the "maps" library, is that the only way?

For reference, my data looks something like this:

```
    Team Name    Total number of home games  Total goals scored at home  Total Goals conceded at home League
```

Code for a single box plot:

```
ggplot(data=final, aes(x=factor(League),
y=(((GS.Home/Total.Home.Games))), colour=League)) + 
geom_boxplot() + geom_point() + stat_summary(fun.y=mean,
geom="point", shape=5, size=4)+ xlab("League")+ 
ylab("Avg goals scored per Home Game")+ 
ggtitle("Average points per Home Game across Leagues")
```

Comment: reshape your data so the avg. goals scored and conceded are in one column, then group by that variable.  This is really basic, any ggplot tutorials will tell you how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm assuming you're talking about using the "melt" function? How would I use it so that avg. goals scored and conceded are in the one column? I think I know how to group it after that.

Comment: exampe: `dat <- data.frame(scored=1:10, conceded=1:10, league=factor(rep(1:5, 2))); library(reshape2); res <- melt(dat, id.vars="league"); aggregate(value ~ variable + league, data=res, mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

[image]

```
# genrate data
df <- data.frame("League" = paste("League", rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 8)), "Team.Name" = rep(paste("Team", LETTERS[1:8]), 3), "Total.number.of.home.games" = sample(30:32, 24, replace = T), "Total.goals.scored.at.home" = sample(7:40, 24, replace = T), "Total.goals.conceded.at.home" = sample(0:9, 24, replace = T))

# install.packages("reshape2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df[,-3], id.vars=c("Team.Name", "League"))
dfm$Average <- gsub("Total", "Average", dfm[,3])

# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(dfm, aes(factor(Average), value))
# p + geom_boxplot()
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(League))) + scale_fill_brewer()

# if you feel like computes summary statistics by hand, that's still an option.
dfm.agg <- aggregate(value ~ variable + League, data=dfm, mean)
dfm.agg[,1] <- gsub("Total", "Average", dfm.agg[,1])
```